# WP7 Emulator, Windows 8, Intel GPU driver

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

After I run my application on WP7 Simulator on Windows 8 x64, Intel GPU driver crashes, with the following in the system event log: "Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered". It doesn't occur immediately after I launch my application, only a few seconds later. After Windows resets the GPU and recovers, the emulator screen stays black.

The GPU is Intel HD 3000 inside 2-nd generation mobile core i5 CPU.

On Windows 7 x64 everything works great, which rules out hardware problems.

I've tried both upgrade 7 -> 8, and clean install. I have WP SDK 7.1.1, Visual Studio 2010 SP1, Windows Market Place Client, XNA Game Studio 4.0 all installed.

How do I fix the emulator and/or Intel GPU driver and/or my app?

P.S. I have another GPU by nVidia. however nVidia has a predefined setting "Windows Phone 7 Emulator" , so I can't switch the graphic processor for the emulator, the option is set to "Integrated graphics" and grayed out. When I used some utility to overcome that defect in nVidia's drivers, XDE.exe started to crash upon launching, saying "0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000".

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://sebastianortiz.cl/glitch-graphics-on-windows-phone-emulator-7-1-with-intel-gma-30004000-hd/

Comment: Roman, thanks, I've already migrated to the newer WP SDK, it uses HyperV-vased emulators and is free from this defect.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked for all: disk/file corruption, other major drivers, BIOS, low level chipset driversand even startup programs/services including antivirus/antispyware/security programs.

and get the latest drivers here [Intel drivers](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx)

Comment: Not yet.. I have a physical device to debug, and gonna try converting my solutions to the next visual studio.